# Reading binary istream byte by byte

Tags: c++, binaryfiles, istream

I was attempting to read a binary file byte by byte using an ifstream.  I've used istream methods like get() before to read entire chunks of a binary file at once without a problem.  But my current task lends itself to going byte by byte and relying on the buffering in the io-system to make it efficient.  The problem is that I seemed to reach the end of the file several bytes sooner than I should.  So I wrote the following test program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    typedef unsigned char uint8;
    std::ifstream source("test.dat", std::ios_base::binary);
    while (source) {
        std::ios::pos_type before = source.tellg();
        uint8 x;
        source >> x;
        std::ios::pos_type after = source.tellg();
        std::cout << before << ' ' << static_cast<int>(x) << ' '
                  << after << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This dumps the contents of test.dat, one byte per line, showing the file position before and after.

Sure enough, if my file happens to have the two-byte sequence 0x0D-0x0A (which corresponds to carriage return and line feed), those bytes are skipped.

- I've opened the stream in binary mode.  Shouldn't that prevent it from interpreting line separators?
- Do extraction operators always use text mode?
- What's the right way to read byte by byte from a binary istream?

MSVC++ 2008 on Windows.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The >> extractors are for formatted input; they skip white space (by
default).  For single character unformatted input, you can use
[`istream::get()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) (returns an `int`, either EOF if the read fails, or
a value in the range [0,UCHAR_MAX]) or `istream::get(char&)` (puts the
character read in the argument, returns something which converts to
`bool`, true if the read succeeds, and false if it fails.

Comment: Wow, it boggles my mind that I can't read a byte from a binary file without a cast of some sort.

Comment: That's because streams are designed for text (even when opened in binary mode).  Generally, when reading real binary date, I'll use the system level routines (open/read/write/close under Unix), rather than bother with iostream.

Comment: One can still use std::skipws so that streams skip white space(and other formatting) even when used with stream operators

Comment: @Ghita I think you mean `std::noskipws`.

Comment: Right sorry you don't want to skip spaces in that case

Answer (score 6):

there is a [read()](https://cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/) member function in which you can specify the number of bytes.

Answer (score 5):

Why are you using formatted extraction, rather than `.read()`?

Comment: Because `source >> x;` is easier to read than `source.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&x));`, and I didn't expect the extraction operator for a single byte on a binary file to do any formatting.

Comment: The `.get()` may be more efficient than `.read()` for single bytes.  But the implementation may have `.read` call `.get` anyway or vice versa.

Comment: source.read((char*)&x) is shorter and C-style cast means the same as reinterpret cast in this case.

Comment: @cubuspl42: Best to avoid getting into the habit of using any C-style casts, though

Answer (score 4):

```
source.get()
```

will give you a single byte. It is unformatted input function.
operator>> is formatted input function that may imply skipping whitespace characters.

Answer (score 2):

As others mentioned, you should use [`istream::read()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/read/). But, if you must use formatted extraction, consider [`std::noskipws`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/noskipws/).

Comment: No, I actually meant noskipws.

Comment: I meant that you can still use formatedd extraction (using stream operators) just that one in that case has to specify skipws